# Best way to connect to Modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have Century Link internet in my home. A ethernet cable runs from a box on the side of the house into living room wall plug.  Only the blue pair of wires are in use.  The wall plug the installer used though is a phone outlet plug. And a phone cable goes to my older netgear wireless router. Can I convert the plug to a regular ethernet plug for use with a newer router.  Or can I use a RJ 11 to RJ45 adapter. And what are the chances the blue pair will be in the correct location?

Comment: Welcome to SU. This is not exactly [on topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here... but from the sound of it, that's a no-go. This sounds like a DSL connection. The only way it can be used is with a DSL modem/router. You should talk to your ISP or some local installer to see what's possible.

Comment: Sure it is on-topic, why wouldn’t it be? It’s about a home internet connection. // The question is a little confusing. What make and model is your current router? Sounds like you simply need a new model which is compatible with your DSL subscription.

Comment: It is not uncommon to use cat5 (network) cable for telephone runs. Using only two wires means that is the telephone run, not an internet run, and supports the idea you are using DSL which is internet over telephone lines. Adapters will probably not help you, and I would guess you may need to review the different bits of equipment in this setup, because either you've failed to mention a modem at all, or the "old netegar wireless router" is your modem. All that said, you should probably look over what ever documentation CenturyLink has for a recommended setup.